# Haskell static computation

Tags: haskell

I was reading the "[Fun with functional dependencies](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.22.7806)"

This part is said to statically computed ie performed at the compile time

```
data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat
three = Succ(Succ(Succ Zero)))
even Zero = True
even (Succ n) = odd n
odd Zero = False
odd (Succ n) = even n

(odd three)
```

But I don't quite get what would be statically computed. And I also don't find anything unusual the compiler to compute to check types

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nothing in that code is computed statically. Note that the code you've posted is from the section "Dynamic Computation", not "Static Computation".